# Buttons going outside of the screen - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I need help...

I was trying to build 3 `buttons` aligned in 1 row and 3 columns inside of a `GridLayout`, and looks its working, but I think I haven't done that right, because if change the size of the text inside the button (`textSize`) the `GridLayout` and the buttons are going outside of the screen. 
I think that I'm setting the `layout_witdh` and/or `layout_height` wrong, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me? Thanks :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.markus.tssproject.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/id0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:tag="0"
                android:text="test tested testing"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/open1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="test tested testing"
                android:texSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/open2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="teste tested testing"/>

        </GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the following in each button

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_weight ="1"
```

you can do this in `LinearLayout` itself, no need of grid layout

Comment: I'm just starting with Android Development. Do you have any example that how could I do this just with the LinearLayout or the best way to do something like this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.markus.tssproject.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:tag="0"
        android:text="test tested testing"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:tag="1"
        android:texSize="20sp"
        android:text="test tested testing" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:tag="2"
        android:text="teste tested testing" />

</LinearLayout>
```